# What is a "closure" in Julia?

Tags: function, julia, closures

I am learning how to write a Maximum Likelihood implementation in `Julia` and currently, I am following [this material](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/julia_tutorials/blob/master/Statistics%20in%20Julia%20-%20Maximum%20Likelihood%20Estimation.ipynb) (highly recommended btw!).
So the thing is I do not fully understand what a **closure** is in Julia nor when should I actually use it. Even after reading the [official documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/functions/#Closures) the concept still remain a bit obscure to me.

For instance, in the tutorial, I mentioned the author defines the log-likelihood function as:

```
function log_likelihood(X, y, β)
    ll = 0.0
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(y)
        zᵢ = dot(X[i, :], β)
        c = -log1pexp(-zᵢ) # Conceptually equivalent to log(1 / (1 + exp(-zᵢ))) == -log(1 + exp(-zᵢ))
        ll += y[i] * c + (1 - y[i]) * (-zᵢ + c) # Conceptually equivalent to log(exp(-zᵢ) / (1 + exp(-zᵢ)))
    end
    ll
end
```

However, later he claims that

> The log-likelihood as we've written is a function of both the data and the parameters, but mathematically it should only depend on the parameters. In addition to that mathematical reason for creating a new function, we want a function **only of the parameters** because **the optimization algorithms in Optim assume the inputs have that property**. To achieve both goals, we'll construct a **closure** that partially applies the log-likelihood function for us and negates it to give us the negative log-likelihood we want to minimize.

```
# Creating the closure
make_closures(X, y) = β -> -log_likelihood(X, y, β)
nll = make_closures(X, y)

# Define Initial Values equal to zero
β₀ = zeros(2 + 1)
# Ignite the optimization routine using `nll`
res = optimize(nll, β₀, LBFGS(), autodiff=:forward)
```

From the paragraph, I understand that we **NEED** to use it because it is how `Optim`'s algorithm works, but I still don't get what is a **closure** in a broader sense.  I will be more than grateful if someone could shed some light on this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context you ask about you can think that closure is a function that references to some variables that are defined in its outer scope (for other cases see the answer by @phipsgabler). Here is a minimal example:

```
julia> function est_mean(x)
           function fun(m)
               return m - mean(x)
           end
           val = find_zero(fun, 0.0)
           @show val, mean(x)
           return fun # explicitly return the inner function to inspect it
       end
est_mean (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = rand(10)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6699650145575134
 0.8208379672036165
 0.4299946498764684
 0.1321653923513042
 0.5552854476018734
 0.8729613266067378
 0.5423030870674236
 0.15751882823315777
 0.4227087678654101
 0.8594042895489912

julia> fun = est_mean(x)
(val, mean(x)) = (0.5463144770912497, 0.5463144770912497)
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> dump(fun)
fun (function of type var"#fun#3"{Vector{Float64}})
  x: Array{Float64}((10,)) [0.6699650145575134, 0.8208379672036165, 0.4299946498764684, 0.1321653923513042, 0.5552854476018734, 0.8729613266067378, 0.5423030870674236, 0.15751882823315777, 0.4227087678654101, 0.8594042895489912]

julia> fun.x
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6699650145575134
 0.8208379672036165
 0.4299946498764684
 0.1321653923513042
 0.5552854476018734
 0.8729613266067378
 0.5423030870674236
 0.15751882823315777
 0.4227087678654101
 0.8594042895489912

julia> fun(10)
9.453685522908751
```

As you can see `fun` holds the reference to the `x` variable from the outer scope (in this case the scope introduced by the `est_mean` function). Moreover, I have shown you that you can even retrieve this value from outside of `fun` as its field (this is typically not recommended but I show this to you to prove that indeed `fun` stores a reference to the object `x` defined in its outer scope; it needs to store this reference as the variabe `x` is used inside the body of the `fun` function).

In the context of estimation, as you have noted, this is useful because `find_zero` in my case requires the function to take only one argument - the `m` variable in my case, while you want the return value to depend both on passed `m` and on `x`.

What is important that once `x` is captured in the `fun` closure it does not have to be in current scope. For instance when I call `fun(10)` the code executes correctly although we are outside of the scope of function `est_mean`. But this is not a problem because `fun` function has captured `x` variable.

Let me give one more example:

```
julia> function gen()
          x = []
          return v -> push!(x, v)
       end
gen (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fun2 = gen()
#4 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fun2.x
Any[]

julia> fun2(1)
1-element Vector{Any}:
 1

julia> fun2.x
1-element Vector{Any}:
 1

julia> fun2(100)
2-element Vector{Any}:
   1
 100

julia> fun2.x
2-element Vector{Any}:
   1
 100
```

Here you see that the `x` variable defined within `gen` function is captured by the anonymous function `v -> push!(x, v)` that I bind to the `fun2` variable. Later when you call `fun2` the object bound to the `x` variable gets updated (and can be referenced to) although it was defined in the `gen` function scope. Although we left the `gen` scope the object bound to the `x` variable outlives the scope because it is captured by the anonymous function we defined.

If something is unclear please comment.

Comment: Great response! I only think that is good to mention that the 2nd approach(with anonymous function) would generate multiple internal signatures and i dunno if it can compile good that way...

Comment: The performance does not depend on whether one uses anonymous or named function. Julia will handle both equally efficiently. From the performance standpoint, what is important, is if the compiler can prove the type of the variable captured in the closure to be concrete (as if it cannot it will have to perform boxing of such a variable and it leads to big performance reduction).

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to complement Bogumił's answer by showing you what he has deliberately left out: a closure does not have to be a function in the strict sense.  In fact, you could write them on your own, if nested functions were disallowed in Julia:

```
struct LikelihoodClosure
    X
    y
end

(l::LikelihoodClosure)(β) = -log_likelihood(l.X, l.y, β)
make_closures(X, y) = LikelihoodClosure(X, y)
nll = make_closures(X, y)
```

Now you are allowed to call `nll(β₀)`, which is an object of type `LikelihoodClosure` with a defined application method.

And that's really all to it.  Anonymous functions are just syntactic sugar for creating instances of objects storing the "fixed variables" from a context.

```
julia> f(x) = y -> x + y
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1) # that's the closure value
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeof(f(1)) # that's the closure type
var"#1#2"{Int64}

julia> f(1).x
1

julia> propertynames(f(1)) # behold, it has a field `x`!
(:x,)
```

And we can even cheat a bit and construct an instance:

```
julia> eval(Expr(:new, var"#1#2"{Int64}, 22))
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> eval(Expr(:new, var"#1#2"{Int64}, 22))(2)
24
```