# Getting the name of a function in a macro

Tags: error-handling, julia

I wrote a macro to make code cleaner and clearer by using error message templates stored in a `dict`. In this example it inserts name of the function, see [discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-function/51223?u=d-se) and [`@__FUNCTION__`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6733), that throws the error.

```
exception = Dict(:foo => ("bar ~", ArgumentError))
macro ⛔(id)
    msg, type = exception[id]
    quote
        msg = replace($msg, "~" => StackTraces.stacktrace()[1].func)
        throw($type(msg))
    end 
end
```

This works fine in `f` that uses positional arguments,

```
f(x, p) = p < 5 ? x : @⛔ foo
f(1, 10)
#> ERROR: ArgumentError: bar f
```

but displays `#..#` when a keyword argument is used.

```
g(x; p = 3) = p < 5 ? x : @⛔ foo
g(1, p = 10)
#> ERROR: ArgumentError: bar #g#N
```

Here `N` is the nth expression evaluated in the session. Redefining `g` with the same syntax increments this number.

I am stuck after I couldn't spot a difference between the code produced by `@⛔`.

```
@macroexpand function f(x, p) p < 5 ? x : @⛔ foo end
@macroexpand function g(x; p = 3) p < 5 ? x : @⛔ foo end
```

**Question**
What is happening in `g` that is different from `f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *is* the name of the method the expanded code is called in -- definitions with keyword arguments are lowered to dispatch helper methods called "keyword sorters": https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/functions/#Keyword-arguments.  These make keywords arguments use dispatch (internally) and compilation just as other functions, instead of just dictionary lookup as e.g. in Python.

I don't think you can do what you want easily in that case, as the conversion process always happens.  Taking a previous stack frame would work, but then you have to know whether you are within a keyword method beforehand.

Maybe the following approach works: pattern match the method name (`#<f>#<N>`), and then check whether it is an actual `kwsorter` method of any method of `f`.  If so, proceed with `f`.

Comment: Thanks - that documentation answers the *why*. For posterity - inserting `if occursin(r"(?<=#)\D+", msg) msg = replace(msg, r"#(\d+)?" => "") end` is robust enough for my use case of a non-exported convenience macro, it seems to work for valid function name syntax (nested/lambda/unicode+digit...).

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Good to hear. But isn't it a problem that closures also follow the same pattern?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem correctly. Inserting a inner constructor `LikelihoodClosure(X,y) = X < 5 ? new(X, y) : @⛔ foo ` and defining `f(x) = y -> y < 10 ? x + y : @⛔ foo` in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972040/14853907) examples gives `LikelihoodClosure` and `#N` as errors when passed invalid values. Looks good to me...?

Comment: `function foo(x); function bar(y); x + y; end; end` will return something like `::var"#bar#2"{Int64}`.